# Stumbling with dynamic parameters, passing Object[] to Object

Tags: java, arrays, types

I've been using a system in which I could tack on as many parameters as I want and the method determines the data-type based on the object, this methods skeleton is as follows:

```
public void sendPacket(int id, Object... data) {
    ....
}
```

This has allowed me to easily send packets with all sorts of information, by just supplying the ID and then the data in the order that I wanted it to be sent over the network.

This became a problem when I needed to dynamically call `sendPacket(Integer, Object);`

Usually I know exactly how much data I need to pass to the sendPacket method, and I pass it manually, however in this case I don't know how many parameters I'm going to send, thus the amount of data I'm sending over the network is unknown.

The method I used to try to do this was to create an `Object[] buffer` which isn't doing what I wanted it to, example below:

```
Object[] buffer = new Object[list.size() * 3];
int bufferIndex = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    buffer[bufferIndex++] = list.get(i).getId();
    buffer[bufferIndex++] = list.get(i).getName();
    buffer[bufferIndex++] = list.get(i).getLevel();
}
sendPacket(5, true, list.size(), buffer);
```

This presents the following [DEBUG] output.

```
[DEBUG]: Packet ID: 5 Data Passed[Boolean]: true
[DEBUG]: Packet ID: 5 Data Passed[Integer]: 1
[Ljava.lang.Object;
```

The [Ljava.lang.Object output is because I have it setup to tell me the class-name of the Object that failed to be converted into usable data.

Here's an example as to how I'm currently interpreting the data being passed to sendPacket

```
for(Object o : data) {
    if(o.getClass().getName().endsWith("Integer")) {
        out.writeInt((int)o);
    }
}
```

There's probably more efficient ways to figure out which type to cast the data to, so if you know one, that information would also be beneficial to myself.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How about creating a different class which holds object type information as well as the actual object. Then you can use the type information to cast buffer object into a specific type.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ConvertUtil {
    private ConvertUtil() {}

    private final static Map<Class<?>, Method> METHOD_MAP = new HashMap<Class<?>, Method>();
    private static Logger                      log        = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConvertUtil.class);

    static {
        try {
            METHOD_MAP.put(Byte.class, Byte.class.getMethod("valueOf", String.class));
            METHOD_MAP.put(Short.class, Short.class.getMethod("valueOf", String.class));
            METHOD_MAP.put(Integer.class, Integer.class.getMethod("valueOf", String.class));
            METHOD_MAP.put(Long.class, Long.class.getMethod("valueOf", String.class));
            METHOD_MAP.put(Boolean.class, Boolean.class.getMethod("valueOf", String.class));
            METHOD_MAP.put(Float.class, Float.class.getMethod("valueOf", String.class));
            METHOD_MAP.put(Double.class, Double.class.getMethod("valueOf", String.class));
            METHOD_MAP.put(String.class, String.class.getMethod("valueOf", Object.class));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("ConvertUtil static is error" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T castValue(Object val, T defaultVal) {
        Method method = METHOD_MAP.get(defaultVal.getClass());
        try {
            if (val != null && val instanceof String) {
                defaultVal = (T) method.invoke(defaultVal.getClass(), val.toString());
            }
            if (val != null && val.getClass().getName().equals(defaultVal.getClass().getName())) {
                defaultVal = (T) val;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("ConvertUtil castValue is error" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return defaultVal;
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, in all honesty this hurts my head, I understand what it's doing for the most part, but I don't completely understand it. Will this solve the issue with the `Object[]` (if so, how) or is this just a different way to handle the class of the `Object` -- Also, how exactly would I call this? `public static castValue(object, object)`